# Replacing old bathroom downlighter

Tags: lighting

How do I open the connecting block on a Knightsbridge low voltage shower light?

I have removed the clip and the cable retainer but am unsure of how to open the plastic case to attach the wiring to the transformer. The plastic cover appears to hinge to the left but I'm afraid of breaking it by using undue force.

Comment: A photo of the unit may be helpful. Where in the world are you located I am thinking about code issues in showers (and what is the age of the home).

Comment: Photos for a question like this are essential. The OP can probably see the power brick right there whilst they typed of the question so it seemed to be clear. But nobody on the internet can see it!!